# How to identify corresponding picks of a delivery with backorders odoo 13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

This is more of a functional qus.
Consider the scenario

- Multi-step route is configured(pick and deliver)
- A huge order is delivered with back-orders, let's say in 3 partial deliveries
- Now, the sale has 6 entries (3 for pick and 3 for WH/OUT)

Is there a way to identify which pick is related to which out-delivery ? If yes, what is the relational field ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

Picking documents has a relationship with stock moves. Stock moves have a relationship with stock moves called Linked Moves (Origin Moves & Destination Moves).

How can you verify this data?

- Go to Inventory > Reporting > Stock Moves
- Find your PICK document number as a Reference
- Open record in a form view and verify record in Destination Moves.
- If you open a destination moves record, it will show you relation OUT picking record in a Reference field.

Example:

[image]